# How to JOIN two tables to find connecting flights?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

[image]Table1 - Travelers

Columns - Name,  NearestAriport,  Destination

Table2 - Flights

Columns - Code, DepartureAirport, DepTime, ArrivalAirport, ArrTime

Problem - To find all possible ways to fly from NearestAiport to Destination.

I need to find all possible flights including DIRECT and CONNECTING flights for Travelers. I am able to find the Direct Flights but facing problem finding connecting flights. (Maximum 1 stop)

If some can help me write query for MS Access DB it would be really helpful.

Comment: could you please provide some input data and expected output in table format

Comment: Yeah, show us some data.  You should not expect to get get a full answer based just on what you wrote above.

Comment: Added rough idea of how data looks like and what kind of result is expected.

Comment: what is the relation between table1 and table2  @SureshLalchandani

Comment: @fa06 there is no direct relationship but you can relate by Airport code. You are literally given two separate tables and have to find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below:

Though the demo is on sqlserver but as it's standard sql I think it will work in MS Access too

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=16bdabc91b6a8f0b8c99944911b7c616)

```
  select 
       X.name,
       x.nearestairport,
       case when X.destinationaiport=X.arrivaleairport then ''
       else X.arrivaleairport end as stop1,
      X.destinationaiport 
   from
    (
       select name, a.nearestairport, a.destinationaiport,b.arrivaleairport
       from table1 a left join table2 b
       on a.nearestairport=b.departureairport
    )X
    left join table2 c 
    on X.destinationaiport=c.arrivaleairport and X.nearestairport=c.departureairport
```

Output:

```
name    nearestairport  stop1   destinationaiport
Jason   JFK                     CLT
Jason   JFK              RDU    CLT
Robert  LAG                     RDU
Wel     CAK              JFK    CLT
Adam    RDU              CLT    JFK
Adam    RDU                     JFK
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I like the logic and its correct but just one change I had to make because MS Access doesn't support case when so I used IIF statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below select to get the Direct/Indirect flight schedules.

```
 SELECT t.Name,t.NearestAirport,cn.DepartureAirport AS Stop,t.DestinationAirport
 FROM Flights f 
 JOIN Travelers t ON t.NearestAirport=f.DepartureAirport
 LEFT JOIN Flights cn ON cn.DepartureAirport=f.ArrivalAirport AND cn.ArrivalAirport = t.DestinationAirport
```

Click https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2968f474760b93f25201e2cd00ccc9d6  for demo
In the demo I have calculated the flight duration